# What does the signal from an NFC pulse look like?

Tags: voltage, power, wireless, nfc

When a smartphone comes into close proximity with a passive NFC tag for example, what does the power pulse from the smartphone 'look' like?
i.e what is the magnitude of power that is supplied, what is its frequency, how long is the pulse?

Comment: How much of the NFC spec have you read?

Comment: admittedly not very much, I am just starting out with electronics, would appreciate a link with the relevant information if possible. :)

Answer (score 2):

NFC is a very complex protocol ! I could understand the NFC specification if I wanted to but it would take me more than a couple of minutes to collect all that information from the specification.

If you have an oscilloscope available to you you could measure it by making a wire loop around an NFC tag, connecting the loop to the oscilloscope and then reading the tag with an NFC enabled smartphone. I might try that myself sometime when I'm bored on a rainy day ;-)

But if you're just starting with electronics then maybe this is a bit too complex to worry about now. What would be your reason for wanting to know this ?

Answer (score 0):

NFC is indeed a very complex protocol with alot of different type of tags and different types of modulation. There is alot of information available on the net, which would take hours to fully read up and understand the NFC protocol. If you really want to know more about NFC I suggest to read up more on it on the web. Looking to your question I can see that you didn't read up alot (or not) on NFC. The carrier frequency of NFC is 13.56 MHz. As for the power that is sent over is a bit hard to say.. I know that the tags in bankcards etc. Have a specification on the maximum amount of power they can get (which is 50mW).

As you are new to electronics i would think about if you really want to know all this about NFC. It is an interesting protocol, but also a very complex and hard to fully understand one.

Answer (score 0):

The other answers are very reasonable, but they are not explaining where to get the information you request.

Most NFC tags or contactless smart cards conform to the ISO-14443 standard, and some others conform to ISO-15693 (there is also a few other schemes). Everything (carrier frequency - which is 13.56MHz, modulation, encodings, power levels, ...) is described in those standards. Unfortunately, those are not public. You must pay to obtain them. A search on the internet on these standard will give you a few hint, but you won't find the full specs for free.

Anyway, nobody really cares about the details regarding the analog part of the communication protocol (what you are asking). Even if you must develop a device that talks to NFC cards/tags, you use a chip that does it (e.g. MFRC531, TRF7960, ...), and it saves you from much of the hassle on that part. Now, even with that, you must still take care of the upper communication layers (anticollision, APDUs, ...), and that is already a *lot* to understand.

So, in the end, I'll go with the same advice as the others: there are simpler things to start with.